# WordPress show only one category, excerpts only, on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a page set up to show only posts from one category, which I'm calling using the php query_posts function. How to I make it so that the posts are displayed as excerpts only, not as full articles?

Here's the code I'm using on the page:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=news&showposts=10'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

*incorporated WordPresses excerpt function:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=news&showposts=10'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Now I'm seeing first a list of the excerpts that I want followed by a repeat of the posts in the entirety...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a core Wordpress method that does that exactly :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

And to control the length of the excerpt :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters

Comment: seems I was hasty in posting the question.  I knew WordPress provided that method, but I just hadn't tried it yet.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if you can't help me out, still.  Now I'm getting both the excerpts and then all of the posts in there entirety right afterwords.  I've ammended my code in the question...

Comment: try to remove the_content and see the behavior. It could be that you somehow execute this twice or so.

Comment: I've edited the question again.  I simplified the code, and I'm still getting two sets of posts - first the excerpts, and then the entire posts.  I just want the excerpts.  It's pretty obvious that `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` is generating the excerpts, but if I try to remove any of the rest of the code, it breaks.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have another loop below the loop that displays the excerpt?